# Windows Explorer Icon Cache is broken. How to solve it?

Tags: caching, icons, windows-explorer, rebuild

I always see broken icons on `.lnk` and `.exe` after compiling, renaming, updating executables, etc. I even tried to re-install Windows to solve the problem. Is there a faster way to solve it other than killing and restarting `explorer.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### By creating a `.bat` file with the following commands, you can solve it under a second through opening it.

---

#### ' rebuild-icon-cache.bat ':

```
del "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /f /q
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
del "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /f /q
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
start "" explorer.exe
:pause
```